# Is there a way to align rotation with snapping target in edit mode?

Tags: modeling

Basically what the title says. Is there a way to be able to align with a face but in edit mode?, here is some pictures of what i want: 
[image: Like this firstabal]
then i change the element to snap to and have it like this : 
[image]
Hope i made myself clear.

Comment: "what the title says" doesn't say in details. Add some screenshots of what you have and what you'd like to get. If guessing you can try to align viewport to the selected face (Shift+Numpad1 / 3 / 7) and add a face with Align to View checked or enable Snap during Transform set to face.

Comment: There i edited it. @Mr Zak

Comment: Is there any special reason to snap that object only in Edit mode? It's much easier with switching to Object mode and snapping there. Without exiting Edit mode this kind of snapping is probably only possible with scripting.